# Windows SD Card reader not working

Tags: windows-10, sd-card

Windows won't mount it, though it shows up in device management and even gives me stats about it, and Linux works with it fine

Comment: "We" need more information. What is the type of the SD Card Reader? Please post the output of `lspci -v` and filter out the data for your card reader. Then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1549612/edit) your question with this info and do not post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had to go into the disk management, then I had to assign it a drive letter.